# Which country's market was my phone meant for?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a phone with Android 4.4.2 (CAT S50). It is of unknown origin (meaning, I don't have a slightest idea whether it was sold in US or in Japan or somewhere else). I'd like to find out what is the country of origin (the market it was supposed to be sold on, to be more precise) for this phone. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you tell the brand and model?

Comment: The brand - **CAT**, the model **S50**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not meant for any specific country as per their [website](http://www.catphones.com/en-gb/support/s50-smartphone).

[3G and 4G details](http://www.catphones.com/en-gb/support/s50-smartphone) show that clearly by mentioning North America and *ROW (Rest of World)*. No mention is made of product variations for different regions/ countries, so it's tough for you to find out where it was sold

AFAIK there is no way to determine where the phone is meant to be *sold*, IMEI gives *country of origin* (exception is Samsung, which assigns different codes to countries/ regions)

**Edit:** OEM website specifically has a flyer saying that s40 is meant for US markets. Absence of any such indicator for s50 strengthens the case for "no specific market"

Comment: I was thinking of more generic data, which would not be phone specific, rather Android specific. Like if the country, for which the phone is meant to be sold in (or a region), would be saved somewhere in the meta data about this specific android phone. The same as it's IMEI code and other info.

Comment: @Reinis if you want something not Android specific, this is the wrong site to ask I'd say ;) I'd recommend checking with [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/) then.